# $\big\langle B_1\cup\cdots\cup B_p\big\rangle=\langle B_1\rangle\oplus\cdots\oplus\langle B_p\rangle$

Tags: linear-algebra, direct-sum

Let
\begin{align}
B_1\,&=\,\big(u_{11},\dots,u_{1n_1}  \big),\dots,B_p\,=\,\big(u_{p1},\dots,u_{pn_p}  \big)
\end{align}
be disjoint linearly independent sets such that
$$B\,=\,B_1\cup\cdots\cup B_p $$
is linearly independent. Then
$$\langle B\rangle
\,=\,\langle B_1\rangle\oplus\cdots\oplus\langle B_p\rangle. $$
My proof :

Since $B_1,\cdots,B_p$ are disjoint and linearly independent, we have $B$ is a basis of $\langle B\rangle$. Hence, for each $u\in\langle B\rangle$, there exists uniquely coefficients $a_{11},\cdots,a_{1n_1},\cdots,a_{p1},\cdots,a_{pn_p}$ such that
\begin{align}
u\,=\,\big(\underbrace{ a_{11}u_{11}+\cdots+a_{1n_1}u_{1n_1}}_{\in\langle B_1 \rangle} \big)+\cdots+\big(\underbrace{ a_{p1}u_{p1}+\cdots+a_{pn_p}u_{pn_p}}_{\in\langle B_p\rangle } \big)
\end{align}
Therefore,
$$\langle B\rangle
\,=\,\langle B_1\rangle\oplus\cdots\oplus\langle B_p\rangle. $$
May anyone tell me if my proof is valid ? My thanks a lot.

Comment: When you say that $B_1,\dots,B_p$ are linearly independent, do you mean that $\bigcup_{j=1}^pB_j$ is linearly independent?

Comment: @ Lorago That's not what the words mean, although I agree that your version is the correct hypothesis.

Comment: @Lorago yeah, that's the condition I want to state, but maybe my statement made some ambiguousness

Comment: @ancientmathematician indeed I am aware, which is why I asked

Comment: You should edit your question to clarify this

Comment: @Lorago if that's the case, is my proof still valid ?

Answer (score 5):

Answer **BEFORE** requiring $B\,=\,B_1\cup\cdots\cup B_p$ to be linearly independent:
You can't assert that $B$ is a basis of $\langle B \rangle$. For example, in the $\mathbb R$-vector space $\mathbb R$, consider $B_1=\{1\},B_2=\{2\}$. Obviously each $B_i$ is linearly independent since they are singletons and also they are disjoint, but $\langle B_1\rangle\cap\langle B_2\rangle=\langle\{1\}\rangle\cap\langle\{2\}\rangle=\mathbb R\cap \mathbb R=\mathbb R\not=\{0\}$.

**Edit**:
If $B\,=\,B_1\cup\cdots\cup B_p$ is linearly independent your proof seems correct to me. I just would add, to make it clearer, that the uniqueness of the coefficients $a_{11},\ldots,a_{1n_1},\ldots,a_{p1},\ldots,a_{pn_p}$ also implies that the expression of $u$ as a sum of vectors of $\langle B_i \rangle$ is unique, from where it follows that the sum is direct.

Comment: I think when I state that "$B_1,\cdots,B_p$  are disjoint linearly independent sets", I mean that each $B_i$ is linear independent and $\mathcal B=\big(B_1,\cdots,B_p\big)$ is also linearly independent, and therefore $\mathcal B$ is a basis of $\langle B\rangle$, that is the case I aimed for, though my statement may make some confusion.

Comment: @PermQi Edited.

Comment: Then I still have a question remain.  So, can there're be a case where $V=V_1\oplus V_2$ and $V_2\leq V_1$ ?

Comment: @PermQi Yes, but only if $V_1=V$ and $V_2=\{0\}$.

Comment: is there no non trivial example ?

Comment: @PermQi No. If $V=V_1\oplus V_2$ then $V_1\cap V_2=\{0\}$. But if $V_2\leq V_1$ then $V_1\cap V_2=V_2$, and hence $V_2=\{0\}$.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I almost forgot that detail of the direct sum. Thank you for reminding me that